# How to use p class and flexbox together

Tags: html, css, text, flexbox

I have four flexed container boxes. I want to put text underneath these boxes in a row.

Any ideas on how I could put these evenly in a row under these containers, as well as any tips to clean up code would be appreciated.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.square {
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #3882f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 33px;
  height: 150px;
}

.subtext {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

p {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square one"></div>
  <div class="square two"></div>
  <div class="square three"></div>
  <div class="square four"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="subtext">
  <p class="sub">
    <div class="box1">
      Wow !
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
      Wow !
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
      Wow !
    </div>
    <div class="box4">
      Wow !
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you remove `<p class="sub">` they will be adjusted properly. Also you have an extra closing `</div>` in 7th line.

Comment: Your HTML needs help. You have extra and unclosed elements. Paragraphs should not contain divs.

Comment: Is there some reason you need your subtext in an entirely different structure? Normally they'd be packaged with the corresponding element above.

Answer (score 3):

I would bundle the boxes and the text. You can keep it separate, but this is less likely to have problems and results in tidier markup.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-direction: row; - not needed (default) */
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.square {
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #3882f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 33px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <p>Paragraph 1.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <p>Paragraph 2.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <p>Paragraph 3.</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="square"></div>
    <p>Paragraph 4.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the advice. This does create a problem. When I add text, the container above expands with it. I want the container to stay the same size no matter what text I put in.

Comment: Then it sounds like the answer by Azu is better.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.square {
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #3882f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 33px;
  height: 150px;
}

.subtext {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square one"></div>
  <div class="square two"></div>
  <div class="square three"></div>
  <div class="square four"></div>
</div>

<div class="subtext">
  <div class="box1">Wow !</div>
  <div class="box2">Wow !</div>
  <div class="box3">Wow !</div>
  <div class="box4">Wow !</div>
</div>

<p>This is a sample line below the boxes</p>
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer better. See [answer].

Comment: Hello. With this answer, the text now overlaps with the other text. Add some extra text to one of the boxes and see how it pushes the text to the sides

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS position absolute to paragraph elements and position relative to parent element.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.square {
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #3882f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 33px;
  height: 150px;
}

.subtext {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position:relative;
}

p {
  
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="square one"></div>
  <div class="square two"></div>
  <div class="square three"></div>
  <div class="square four"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="subtext">
  <p class="sub">
    <div class="box1">
      Wow !
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
      Wow !
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
      Wow !
    </div>
    <div class="box4">
      Wow !
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Absolute positioning tends to cause as many problems as it solves. I wouldn't use it here. It's not necessary.

Comment: if you don't to use absolute then you try to combine divs, say like both divs marge into one dive " square and box1 "

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in invisible elements to group them and use `text-align: center`. Here's an example.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 8px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.flexbox article {
  text-align: center;
}

.flexbox div {
  font-size: 4em;
  width: 96px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #3882f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 33px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <article><div id="box1">1</div><p>One</p></article>
  <article><div id="box2">2</div><p>Two</p></article>
  <article><div id="box3">3</div><p>Three</p></article>
  <article><div id="box4">4</div><p>Four</p></article>
</div>
```

Comment: @isherwood I have updated it.

Comment: They're not quite centered correctly.

Comment: @isherwood In what way? In Chromium on Linux they seem fine.

Comment: There's a much larger gap on the right than on the left. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmOrQ.png